# su: Authentication Failure, stopped working

Tags: authentication, su

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04. I used `su` command, entered my accounts password. It worked successfully for few times. 
Then I got Authentication Failure, now I'm not sure if I entered wrong password and locked it or if there is some other issue.

I'm new to Linux and would appreciate your help.

Comment: `sudo` uses your own password; *not* `su` which uses the other specified user's password.  Are you sure `su` is what you need, and not `sudo`?

Comment: Hi Thomas,
I wanted to install wifi driver but after trying multiple times it was not installed. So i thought of first entering to root and then installing the same. I had used 'su' before it worked fine.

Comment: there is no `root` password in Ubuntu by default, you probably meant to do `sudo su` which would drop you to a root prompt.  (You really should use `sudo -i` though)  If you had a root password then that's different, but you **really** should not be dropping into a root prompt and should be using `sudo` with any commands that need run as superuser.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that helped. I just have one more query. If I use 'sudo -command' then the command will run as super user and it doesn't require any password, right? I just have my account password and haven't set any other password.

Comment: `sudo command`, yes, will try and execute the command as superuser *if* your user is in the sudoers file.  (Which it probably is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're confusing some commands up and how to properly execute things as superusers (such as wifi driver installations)

Firstly, `su` does not execute commands as superuser, not unless you're executing it with `su root -c 'COMMANDHERE WITH ARGUMENTS'`.  However, by default there **is no root user/password** you can use `su` with on Ubuntu, so you can't make this work properly.

Secondly, to execute commands as superuser, you should be doing `sudo command`, which will execute the command as superuser, provided  your user is in the `/etc/sudoers` file or in the `sudo` group.  This is the *commonly accepted* practice for Ubuntu.

Thirdly, if you **absolutely** need to get into a root prompt (and you VERY RARELY would need to do this), you can do so with `sudo -i` which is a little more secure since it requires you to be a sudoer to execute the command.